# Extract all text after last occurrence of a special character

Tags: r, regex

I have the string in R

```
BLCU142-09|Apodemia_mejicanus
```

and I would like to get the result

```
Apodemia_mejicanus
```

Using the stringr R package, I have tried

```
str_replace_all("BLCU142-09|Apodemia_mejicanus", "[[A-Z0-9|-]]", "")
# [1] "podemia_mejicanus"
```

which is almost what I need, except that the A is missing.

Comment: What if you have `a|b|c|Apodemia_mejicanus`? I think you need `sub(".*\\|", "", x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can match one or more characters that are not a `|` (`[^|]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by `|` in `str_remove` to remove that substring

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(str1, "^[^|]+\\|")
#[1] "Apodemia_mejicanus"
```

---

If we use `[A-Z]` also to match it will match the upper case letter and replace with blank (`""`) as in the OP's `str_replace_all`

#### data

```
str1 <- "BLCU142-09|Apodemia_mejicanus"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```r
sub(".*\\|", "", x)
```

This will remove all text up to and including the last pipe char. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2rrkj/1). Details:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\|` - a `|` char (`|` is a special regex metacharacter that is an alternation operator, so it must be escaped, and since string literals in R can contain string escape sequences, the `|` is escaped with a double backslash).

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/kanIlm):

```r
x <- c("BLCU142-09|Apodemia_mejicanus", "a|b|c|BLCU142-09|Apodemia_mejicanus")
sub(".*\\|", "", x)
## => [1] "Apodemia_mejicanus" "Apodemia_mejicanus"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always choose to `_extract` rather than `_remove`:

```
s <- "BLCU142-09|Apodemia_mejicanus"
stringr::str_extract(s,"[[:alpha:]_]+$")
## [1] "Apodemia_mejicanus"
```

Depending on how permissive you want to be, you could also use `[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+` as your target.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple:

```
substring(my_string, regexpr("|", my_string, fixed = TRUE) + 1L)
```